# T-SQL: similar Id in same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like that and I need result just UserId 11, because UserId 12 is no lessonId 103 but still getting result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM LessonList
WHERE
    (LessonId = 102 and LessonValue = 1002)
    or
    (LessonId = 103 and LessonValue = 1003)
    or
    (LessonId = 102 and LessonValue = 1008)
```

Output:

```
Id       UserId       LessonId       LessonValue
1        11           102            1002
2        11           103            1003
3        12           102            1008
```

I need result like this:

```
Id       UserId       LessonId       LessonValue
1        11           102            1002
2        11           103            1003
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
SELECT userid
FROM LessonList
WHERE (LessonId = 102 and LessonValue IN (1002, 1008)) or
      (LessonId = 103 and LessonValue = 1003)
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LessonId) = 2;
```

This will return users who have two lesson ids.  Because of the `WHERE` clause, this implies that they have both 102 and 103.  The `IN` just simplifies the query logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM LessonList
WHERE
    (LessonId = 102 and LessonValue = 1002)
    or
    (LessonId = 103 and LessonValue = 1003)
   and lessonvalue<>1008
```